# Kivy pass data from one screen to another screen and to another class directly

Tags: python, kivy

I'm new to Kivy and I'm trying out my first app. I'm struggling with the direct exchange of data between classes. I've already tried out some suggestions for implementation, which were mentioned here. Unfortunately without success.
I would like to access the "TextInput" in other classes directly, assign the text to a variable (value) and print it to the commandline.
Im obviously wrong, but shouldn't something like this schema work: app.screenmanager.screen.textinput.text?
The last thing I tried is something desperate like this: App.get_running_app().root.ids.sm.get_screen('settingscreen').ids.id_textinp
Error in Trigger was:'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'
Error in MainScreen was:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'root'

Questions:

1. Is the data of a class private?
2. Is it possible to print out "value" in the class "MainScreen"? Because im not sure if the complete "SettingScreen" including the "TextInput is already created, at this moment. Also it's executed only once. Need to schedule a function for print (value)?
3. How can the data be accessed in this both cases (class MainScreen and class Trigger)? The "compare" function of class "Trigger" runs cyclically, so at least here it should be possible to print out "value"
4. Is there an other (best practise) way?

Thank you in advance for helping!

My Testcode reduced to the necessary:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from functools import partial

import requests
import time

class Trigger:
    def compare(callbacktime,test2, test3):
        value="Trigger: nothing in here"
        #value = App.get_running_app().root.ids.sm.get_screen('settingscreen').ids.id_textinp
        print (value)
        pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)        

        self.alert=Trigger
        paraDict={'test2':"222",'test3':"333"}
        value="MainScreen: nothing in here"
        #value = App.get_running_app().root.ids.sm.get_screen('settingscreen').ids.id_textinp
        print (value)
        Clock.schedule_interval(partial(self.alert.compare,**paraDict), 1)

        self.btn2 = Button(text='Settings', size_hint=(.15, .1), pos_hint={'center_x': .9, 'center_y': .95})
        self.add_widget(self.btn2)
        self.btn2.bind(on_press = self.screen_transition_alarm)

    def screen_transition_alarm(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = 'settingscreen'

class SettingScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SettingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Hi Im The SettingScreen', size_hint=(.45, .1), pos_hint={'x': .05, 'y': .9}))

        self.btn = Button(text='back', size_hint=(.15, .1), pos_hint={'center_x': .9, 'center_y': .95})
        self.add_widget(self.btn)
        self.btn.bind(on_press = self.screen_transition_back)  

        self.hour = TextInput(id='id_textinp', text='1337', size_hint=(.3, .3), pos_hint={'center_x': .3, 'center_y': .7},input_filter="int",multiline=False, font_size=30, halign="center")
        self.add_widget(self.hour)

    def screen_transition_back(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = 'mainscreen'

sm = ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition())
sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='mainscreen',id='id_mainscreen'))
sm.add_widget(SettingScreen(name='settingscreen', id='id_settingscreen'))

class MainApp(App):
    title = 'mainprogram'

    def build(self):
        return sm #return Screenmanager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Adding `ids` in python code will not place them in any `ids` dictionary. That must be done in `kv`.

Comment: Try something like `App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('settingscreen').hour`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought everything done in kv can also be done in python code.

Comment: App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('settingscreen').hour works in the Trigger class! It returns the object of TextInput. With App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('settingscreen').hour.text I finally got the Text of TextInput. Thank you as well!